# Should spaces and non-english characters be allowed in uploaded file (image)?

Tags: file-upload, seo, whitespace, filenames

I am implementing uploading image feature and struggling when deciding whether to strip off non-english chars and spaces.

In my language, we have alphabetical characters just like in English except for a few: â, ơ, ù, ...

For example:

1. An original file name would be: 145_Quản trị năng lượng cấp cao_ori
2. If I strip off non-english chars: 145_Quan tri nang luong cap cao_ori
3. If I take a step further replacing spaces: 145_Quan-tri-nang-luong cap-cao_ori
4. I may as well replacing spaces only: 145_Quản-trị-năng-lượng-cấp-cao_ori

I'm concerned about SEO ability of the image and browsers' support for loading images like these.

Which one of the above approaches would be the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've got two issues -- and it's better to separate these, to understand them clearly.

1. What characters are valid for the filename on disk?  These determine the FILENAME you should upload & store as. This is OS- and filesystem-dependent. For portability, you may choose *not* to store accented characters.
2. What characters are valid for the title & URL?  These determine the TITLE or URL you will store & present these under, and will be visible to SEO. I think you should definitely use the Vietnamese here if possible -- as people will be searching for that!

According to modern URL standards, you can use UTF-8 encoding followed by % byte-encoding in a URL to encode all Unicode characters.

Long story short, I'd use two columns in the database, keep the filename simple & portable, but expose the full UTF-8 as title & in the URL.

See:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding%5Fin%5Fa%5FURI